# Jquery insertBefore issue

Tags: jquery

I am having troubles getting my insert element task done here and I have been spending hours for it.

I tried to insert elements by class name when user clicks the button. I also have css setup in the script. My problem is that only the first element has css property but not the rest. Can anyone help me about it? Thanks so much!

Jquery

```
  //when users clicks the button

   var imgForClass = $("<img src='images/anim.gif' class='imgAbs'>");

   var cssProp = {'position':'absolute',
                       'z-index':99,
                       'top': topPos,  //topPos is the position that the element I want to attach to.
                       'left': leftPos //leftPos is the position that the element I want to attach to.
            }

   //detect if the element has id of 'cons'
   if($element.is('#cons'){                
               imgForClass.insertBefore('.conElement');
               imgForClass.css(cssProp) 
    }
```

Html

```
<div>
<img src='a.jpg'/>
<img id='cons' src='b.jpg'/>
</div>      

//the new element will be inserted here but only the first element has css property(z-index...etc)
<div class='conElement'>
<img src='b.jpg'/>
</div>      

//the new element will be inserted here but has no css property(z-index...etc)
<div class='conElement'>
<img src='b.jpg'/>
</div>      

//the new element will be inserted here but has no css property(z-index...etc)
<div class='conElement'>
<img src='b.jpg'/>
</div>      

//the new element will be inserted here but has no css property(z-index...etc)
<div class='conElement'>
<img src='b.jpg'/>
</div>   


...more <div>
```

Comment: Your html is invalid: you are not supposed to use the same `id` for more than one element. This will cause problems in JS code that tries to reference said elements by their `id`. To identify similar elements give them a common class.

Comment: thx nnnnnn. but I use copied and paste here and didn't notice that. my actual codes don't have repeated id

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem here is that you are expecting the imgForClass variable after the insertBefore() method call to  now be a reference to all of the newly inserted img tags, and I believe it is only holding a reference to the first one. So perhaps something like the following would help you

```
if($element.is('#cons'){                
               imgForClass.insertBefore('.conElement');
               $('.imgAbs').css(cssProp);
}
```

on a side note, its not  good practice to have multiple elements on a page with the same ID as you are doing with all the

```
<img id='cons' src='b.jpg'/>
```

Comment: I ran the snippets of code you supplied and it worked for me?. Would you be able to expand your code a bit and elaborate on where $element, topPos and leftPos are being defined?

Comment: Thx OJay, it's very hard for me to do that because it's a large project, but thanks for telling me my snippet works so I would know where to look.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't meaning that your snippets work verbatim, once I made the change that I proposed they worked. I can confirm that the imgForClass variable is only holding a reference to 1 item, as per my suggestion to specifically get all items that you require, hence the ($('.imgAbs').css(cssProp)) but without knowing how topPos, lefPos and $element are set, its hard to see the full picture

Comment: I did some fiddles to try to help. First one is http://jsfiddle.net/nhQfQ/1/ which is your code verbatim (well removing the topPos and leftPos as well as the $element), next one is as per my recommendation  http://jsfiddle.net/CkRLf/1/ - Sorry for the pictures, but I just found them fast

Comment: Thanks for the fiddle. I still have problems getting it done even thought I used your codes. so weird....

Comment: Must be something in the topPos and leftPos variables?!

Comment: but they shouldn't effect the element NOT getting css property right?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16676/discussion-between-ojay-and-rouge)

Answer (score 0):

I think this will do:

```
if($element.is('#cons'){                
    imgForClass.insertBefore('.conElement').css(cssProp);
}
```